# Steipler: No more gilgulim?

Tags: reincarnation

I heard in a shiur that the Steipler said that there are no more gilgulim, this is the last chance. Anyone have a source?

Comment: I thought I heard this b'sheim the Gra.....

Comment: @Yehuda maybe Steipler b’sheim haGra

Comment: This would contradict the Chofetz Chaim in various places that there will be gilgulim until whatever needs to be rectified is rectified. Unless he meant because Mashiach is coming very soon, but nobody knows that.

Comment: I have heard the same thing but rather that now there are only עיבורים which answers above

Comment: @zunior what do you mean by עיבורים? Like souls that didn’t yet rectify themsleves?

Comment: It means a form of reincarnation where the two people are not the same but rather one is helping the other.

Comment: Its explained in the first few chapters of שער הגילגולים